# Relate an item in the database to the User Session ID - Yesod Haskell Postgree

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

Im doing a PetShop System. I have a form that list all Animals. I already have Session in my Project. How can i add a Animal linking to session ID and in the page that list's the animals, list just the animals of that user.

This is the part related it.

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Animals 
   nome Text
   idade Int
   racaid RacaId
   deriving Show

Users 
   nome Text
   login Text
   senha Text
   deriving Show

Raca
   nome Text
   apelido Text sqltype=varchar(10)
   deriving Show
|]

--Form that include animals
formAnimal :: Form Animals
formAnimal = renderDivs $ Animals <$>
           areq textField "Nome: " Nothing <*>
           areq intField "Idade: " Nothing <*>
           areq (selectField racas) "Raca" Nothing

--Form that include Users
formUser :: Form Users
formUser = renderDivs $ Users <$>
           areq textField "Nome: " Nothing <*>
           areq textField "Login: " Nothing <*>
           areq passwordField "Password: " Nothing

--Function do include animals
getAnimalR :: Handler Html
getAnimalR = do
           (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost formAnimal
           defaultLayout $ do 
           toWidget [cassius|
              label
                  color:blue;
           |]
           [whamlet|
                 <form .form-horizontal method=post enctype=#{enctype} action=@{AnimalR}>
                     ^{widget}
                     <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar Animal">
           |]

--Part that list all Animals (need to list just of the User)
getListarAnimalR :: Handler Html
getListarAnimalR = do
             listaAnm <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc AnimalsNome]
             defaultLayout $ [whamlet|
                 <h1> Animais cadastrados:
                 $forall Entity pid animals <- listaAnm
                     <a href=@{ChecarAnimalR pid}> #{animalsNome animals} 
                     <form method=post action=@{ChecarAnimalR pid}> 
                         <input type="submit" value="Deletar Animal"><br>
             |] >> toWidget [lucius|
                form  { display:inline; }
                input { background-color: #ecc; border:0;}
             |]

--Function that get the User. Check in database if contain any user with that login and pass
postLoginR :: Handler Html
postLoginR = do
           ((result, _), _) <- runFormPost formLogin
           case result of 
               FormSuccess ("admin","admin") -> setSession "_ID" "admin" >> redirect AdminR
               FormSuccess (login,senha) -> do 
                   user <- runDB $ selectFirst [UsersLogin ==. login, UsersSenha ==. senha] []
                   case user of
                       Nothing -> redirect LoginR
                       Just (Entity pid u) -> setSession "_ID" (pack $ show $ fromSqlKey pid) >> redirect (PerfilR pid)
```

Comment: why relate to the session instead of the user-id? Sessions will change for the same user

Comment: The session isn't the user_id ? If not can session guard User-Id to use in insert, selects ?How can i do it ?